# order by sql query error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
$post_items = $db->query("SELECT post_id,content,date,category_id 
        FROM post_items JOIN user ON(post_items.user_id = user.user_id) WHERE post_items.user_id =" . $userid)
```

how can I include order by in my case? I tried

```
$post_items = $db->query("SELECT post_id,content,date,category_id 
        FROM post_items JOIN user ON(post_items.user_id = user.user_id) WHERE post_items.user_id =" . $userid ."order by post_id");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, apply space between field and order keyword, and also use tablename if columnaname is ambiguse in query where are use join :

```
$post_items = $db->query("SELECT post_id,content,date,category_id 
        FROM post_items inner JOIN user ON post_items.user_id = user.user_id  
         WHERE post_items.user_id =" . $userid ." order by post_items.post_id ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space before `order`:

```
." order by post_id"
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add one space before the "ORDER BY post_id" to become " ORDER BY post_id".